# Is it possible to call parent window (cpp code) to child window (electron js/node js)

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, electron

Is it possible to call parent window (cpp code) to child window (electron js/node js)? My main goal is to achieve modal dialog.

modal dialog: A modal dialog is a window that forces the user to interact with it before they can go back to using the parent application.

Comment: thank you for the description of a modal dialog

Comment: Use the window.parent object